Sending e-mails from MS Word (via Outlook) stores sent mail within wrong account
My client has Office 2021, and within Outlook they have two IMAP accounts: A and B

When sending email from Outlook, everything works as intended (mail sent from A is saved into A/Inbox/Sent, same for B).
When sending e-mails via Word using a validated "From:" account, the sent mail is always stored within A/Inbox/Sent

Is there a workaround (I think this may be a bug)?

Yes, Word and Outlook will use whatever is marked as the default email as the sending email address on a mail merge. You need to set a specific account as the default account within Outlook:

Go to: File → Options → Mail → Send → Messages
Check box: Always use the default account when composing new messages

I also found a thread-like note that you can refer to

Thanks. Actually, starting from your reponse, it is ever more stupid. You need to navigate to "Data files" tab. Whatever "data file" is default - is the one into which sent mails are stored when sending from Word. A bug, apparently (it should obey sender account). Thanks!

Mails sent from Word are always, no matter the user choice of sender account, saved within the Sent folder of the "default data file

Resolve by going to the Acounts → Tab: Data files

